# Is it safe for multiple threads to use the same EventHubClient object to publish events?

Tags: .net, azure-eventhub

Is eventHubClient.SendAsync thread safe? That is, can I get one instance of EventHubClient from EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString() and use it to write to event hub from multiple threads. This the code I am using, Logger.Log will be used by many threads in a asp.net web application.

Could not find the answer for this in the documentation..

```
class Logger
{
    ...
    static EventHubClient eventHubClient;

    static Logger()
    {
        eventHubClient = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(hubConnectionString, eventHubName);
    }

    public static void Log()
    {
        ...
        eventHubClient.SendAsync(eventObject);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EventHubClient.SendASync() is totally thread-safe.

One side note though. Each client will maintain a single TCP connection underneath. This connection can become a bottle-neck when there are large number of parallel sends waiting to either be queued or in the queue to be processed. So consider monitoring number of pending sends for sometime and scale out your sends to multiple clients if needed.

Comment: thanks! but, and forgive the noob question - how do you monitor pending sends? and what's the worse that can happen if pending sends keep increasing - some get dropped?